# Promote MySQL Table Partition to Table

Tags: mysql, partitioning, alter-table

My Google Searching skills were not enough to find a solution to this. If possible, how can I promote a partition on a table to a table on its own?

Let's assume I have `part0`, `part1`, and `part2`. Is there any `ALTER TABLE` that I can give that converts `part0` to a new table?

My thought process was, since the data is already existing in a separate file on disk, the table creation process may be faster than creating a new table using a `SELECT` query.

Comment: have you tried a materialized view https://fromdual.com/mysql-materialized-views

Comment: I actually intend to drop the partition from the original table and do some other ETL work with the new table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need `SELECT`. This can be done with pure DDL.

For this example, let say the partitioned table is as follows:

1. Database `mydb`
2. Table `mytable`
3. Partitions (`part0`,`part1`,`part2`)

This can be tricky but here is goes

```
USE mydb
CREATE TABLE mynewtable LIKE mytable;
ALTER TABLE mynewtable REMOVE PARTITIONING; 
ALTER TABLE mytable
    EXCHANGE PARTITION p0
    WITH TABLE mynewtable
    WITHOUT VALIDATION
;
ALTER TABLE mytable DROP PARTITION p0;
```

What this does is first make `mynewtable` without any partitions and the same schema in all other aspects. Then, it swaps the `mynewtable` table with `part0`.

If you are not sure of this, then run

```
USE mydb
CREATE TABLE mynewtable LIKE mytable;
ALTER TABLE mynewtable REMOVE PARTITIONING; 
ALTER TABLE mytable
    EXCHANGE PARTITION p0
    WITH TABLE mynewtable
    WITHOUT VALIDATION
;
```

Examine the rows in `mynewtable` and the new `part0` and make sure

- `mynewtable` has the data from the original `part0`
- The new `part0` should be empty

Once you are sure the transposition worked then run

```
ALTER TABLE mytable DROP PARTITION p0;
```

Please test this in a lab or sqlfiddle. **GIVE IT A TRY !!!**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a `PARTITION` is a `TABLE`.  However, it takes some special commands to turn a partition into a table or vice versa.

See "transportable tablespaces" and FLUSH TABLES ptable FOR EXPORT; ALTER TABLE ptable DISCARD TABLESPACE; ALTER TABLE ptable IMPORT TABLESPACE.  The details are different between MySQL 5.6 and 5.7+.

http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint#use_cases_for_partitioning has links to a few places that discuss the techniques.